# Can a command determine the event sequence that invoked it?

Tags: key-bindings, commands, event-sequence

I have a command that I would like to bind to multiple key sequences differing only in the final decimal digit (e.g. `C-. 0`, `C-. 1`, ..., `C-. 9`).  The command needs to determine that final digit.

I would prefer not to have 10 distinct bindings, each passing a distinct argument to a shared implementation.  So I am wondering whether emacs keeps around the event sequence that triggers a command.  Surely the self-insert-command has such a capability (though of course it is written in C).

Comment: Looks like you actually want to have a command with a numeric argument, i.e., you want to bind `C-.` to a command with, e.g.,  `(interactive "e")` as first form. Try the help for `interactive` for alternatives. (You could also use a numeric prefix argument.)

Comment: As initially described perhaps.  That is not possible in my case because these bindings are part of a larger scheme: "C-. m 0", "C-. m 1", ..., "C-. m 9" and "C-. x 0", C-. x 1", ... "C-. x 9".

Answer (score 7):

`C-h f this-command-keys`:

> this-command-keys is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> (this-command-keys)
>
> For more information check the manuals.
>
> Return the key sequence that invoked this command.
>   However, if the command has called `read-key-sequence`, it returns
>   the last key sequence that has been read.
>   The value is a string or a vector.
>
> See also `this-command-keys-vector`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Command Loop Info](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Loop-Info.html).

Comment: Thanks Drew.  That is exactly the suggestion I needed.  (I am not surprised that you were the one to provide the proper answer :-).

Comment: If it answers the question then consider accepting it. Having an accepted answer can help other users learn from the Q & A.

Answer (score 1):

`self-insert-command` is indeed written in C but could just as well be written in Elisp (it's just a result of historical evolution).  The variable it uses to figure out which key was pressed is `last-command-event`.

Comment: Stefan, The documentation on `last-command-event` is rather sparse.  I assume that in a mult-key sequence `last-command-event` contains only the final key.  Is that correct?  It is simply an integer?  To check for a modified key would I write something like

Comment: `(= last-command-event (kbd "C-["))`

Comment: Yes, an "event" is a single key press (possibliy with modifiers).  It can be an integer (a character, possibly with modifiers) or a symbol, or a structured event (e.g. a moue-click).  For your example, the value would be `?\C-\[` which is the integer 27.  `(kbd "C-[")` is not quite right, since `kbd` handle key *sequences*, i.e. sequences of events rather than single events.  IOW, `(aref (kbd "C-[") 0)` would give you the right answer.  There are various functions to extract data from events; try `C-h f event- TAB` to see a list of them.